# IDA Pro v7 installation problem in VM

Tags: ida, windows, virtual-machines, vmware

I have different problem.

I created VM (windows7x86SP1) with VMware Fusion on Mac OSX. When I try to install IDA Pro, I have a such a error. But I couldn't find any solution. I removed VM than installed again. But result is same.

Maybe someone knows and can help me.

[image]

Comment: IDA is a 64-bit application

Comment: Maybe but I guess it is supporting x86. Because I was using with Windows7x86. But I do not know what happen after while.

Comment: Try these ready-made VM from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ use Win10 x64.

Comment: It is working on x64.

Answer (score 3):

IDA 7.0 is x64 application, i.e. both ida.exe and ida64.exe are built for x64, despite the naming. So you won't be able to run 7.0 on x86 at all. Use IDA versions previous to 7.0.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried on x64 than it works.